# PHP: Getting Multiple Variable Values From For Looping

Tags: php, for-loop

this is my another problem, thi is my code:

```
for($d = 0; $d < $cnt; $d++){
                $fetchit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ar_subkategori WHERE id_subkategori = $detail_sub[$d]");
                $datafetch = mysql_fetch_array($fetchit);
                $id_values = $datafetch['id_subkategori'];
                if ($id_values == $getsubsel['id_subkategori']){
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox' value='$getsubsel[id_subkategori]' checked> <span style='font-size:10px; color:#FFA412;'>[ID: $getsubsel[id_subkategori]]</span> $getsubsel[nama_subkategori] <span style='color:#FFA412; font-style:italic; font-size:12px;'>*Ini adalah sub dari ID: $getsubsel[id_subkategori_induk]</span></br>";
                }               
            }
            if ($id_values != $getsubsel['id_subkategori']){
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox' value='$getsubsel[id_subkategori]'> <span style='font-size:10px; color:#FFA412;'>[ID: $getsubsel[id_subkategori]]</span> $getsubsel[nama_subkategori] <span style='color:#FFA412; font-style:italic; font-size:12px;'>*Ini adalah sub dari ID: $getsubsel[id_subkategori_induk]</span></br>";
            }
```

The problem is the value form `$id_values` is always show ID = 30, while that the value should be show is 1, 5, 10, 30. How to fix it?

Thanks before, Salam..

Comment: I cant find `$id_values` in code

Comment: @Deonia `$id_values = $datafetch['id_subkategori'];`

Comment: That's your problem then. You're overwriting the variable on every iteration. You might want to turn that into an array.

Comment: @CORRUPT Lolz I even copied the code and made search in text editor and it also results me nothing :) something happened to my eyes balls

Comment: What is $detail_sub and what is $count?

Comment: @Deonia you can find it after ' $datafetch = mysql_fetch_array($fetchit);'

Comment: Can you show what is the value you are getting in here `$detail_sub[$d]`

Comment: @Deonia $detail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ar_produk_detail WHERE id_produk = $_GET[id]");
  $jml_detail = mysql_num_rows($detail);
  while ($get_detail = mysql_fetch_array($detail)){
   $detail_sub[] = $get_detail['id_subkategori'];
  }

Comment: @DimasAryaTejaKusumah its seems your problem is in here `$detail_sub[$d]` in select query . Try to embrace it with curl braces  `$detail_sub[{$d}]`

Comment: i have to try your answer, and i have this issue 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in bla bla bla'

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array variable to be shown inside "" you must surrond it with {} like this:

```
"{$getsubsel['id_subkategori']}"
```

That's why you are seeing the variable name instead of it value.

Answer (score 0):

May be this ..

```
$fetchit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ar_subkategori WHERE id_subkategori = $detail_sub[" . strval($d) . "]");
```

or

```
$fetchit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ar_subkategori WHERE id_subkategori = $detail_sub['{$d}']");
```

Comment: i have to try your answer, and i have this issue 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in bla bla bla'

Comment: i've try both, and the same issue is show again..  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 $fetchit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ar_subkategori WHERE id_subkategori = '".$detail_sub[$d]."'");
```